# Cannot use SplFileObject with directories

Tags: php

I used splfileobject to open the file in PHP. File is in the same directory below code is work fine. If file is another directory and is shows error like Cannot use SplFileObject with directories

```
    $file = new SplFileObject("files/".$file_name);
    $row = 1;
    while (!$file->eof()) {         
      $data[$row] = $file->fgetcsv();    
      $row++;
    }
```

Comment: What is your code supposed to do with a directory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to skip directories, then `is_dir()` will allow you to check the type and skip it...

```
if ( is_dir("files/".$file_name ) == false ) {
    $file = new SplFileObject("files/".$file_name);
    $row = 1;
    while (!$file->eof()) {         
      $data[$row] = $file->fgetcsv();    
      $row++;
    }
}
```